# Splitting an array finding minimum difference between the sum of two subarray in distributed environment

Tags: javascript, algorithm, distributed-computing, distributed, distributed-system

This problem I was asked yesterday. I had to write a code to split the array into two parts such that the difference between the sum of these two part would be minimum.

Here is the code I wrote with the complexity *O(n)*

```
function solution(a) {
  let leftSum = 0;
  let rightSum = a.reduce((acc, value) => acc + value ,0);
  let min = Math.abs(rightSum - leftSum);
  a.forEach((item, i) => {
   leftSum += a[i];
   rightSum -= a[i]; 
   const tempMin = Math.abs(rightSum - leftSum);
   if(tempMin < min) min = tempMin;
  })
  return min;
}
```

But then I was asked if the input array is of length 10 million, how would I solve this problem in a distributed environment?

I am new to distributed programming, need help in this.

Comment: If it is just 10 million, the latency of the network might just be too much of an overhead. If network should not be a problem, you can assign individual chunks to each compute node and let the nodes calculate a solution for their chunks. This way, you can also parallelize the summation at the beginning. Each node will also need the sum of values left and right of their chunk.

Comment: but if the nodes calculate their own minimum differences of chunks, the combined result will be different from the result in non distributed environment. we can parallelize the summation, but apart from that i don't know how to calculate the minimum difference parallely

Comment: The sum between 2 sub-arrays with equal lengths?

Comment: Are negative values allowed in the array? This would complicate things.

Comment: @zer00ne No, the length may vary

Comment: @PeterCheng Yes, negative values are allowed

Answer (score 3):

If you have `N` node,s then split the array into `N` sequential subarrays; this will give you `N` sequential sums.  Take a pass to determine which subarray contains the desired split point.  The difference between the "before" and "after" sums is your bias target for the next phase ...

Now divide that "middle" array into `N` pieces.  Again, you look for the appropriate split point, except that now you know the exact result you'd like (since you have the array sum and your missing difference).

Repeat that second paragraph until you can fit the entire subarray into one node *and* that's the fastest way to finish the computation for your project.

---

You can speed this up somewhat by keeping a cumulative sum at each value; this will allow you to find the appropriate split point somewhat faster at each stage, as you can use a binary or interpolation search for every stage after the first.

Answer (score 2):

Given an array of length N, and given M available nodes, divide the array into chunks of size N/M. Each node computes the sum of its chunk, and reports back. The total is computed by adding the partial sums. Then the total and the partial sums are distributed to each of the nodes. Each node determines the best split point within its chunk (the local minimum), and reports back. The global minimum is computed from the local minimums.

For example, if the array has 10 million entries, and 200 nodes are available, the chunk size is 50000. So each node receives 50000 numbers, and reports back the sum. The total of the array is computed by adding the 200 partial sums. Then each node is given the total, along with the 200 partial sums. The information at each node now consists of

- a chunk number
- the 50000 array entries for that chunk
- the array total
- the 200 partial sums

From that information, each node can compute its local minimum. The global minimum is computed from the 200 local minimums.

In the ideal case, where network bandwidth is infinite, network latency is zero, and any number of nodes can be used, the chunk size should be `sqrt(N)`. So each node receives `sqrt(N)` array elements, and then receives `sqrt(N)` partial sums. Under those ideal conditions, the running time is `O(sqrt(N))` instead of `O(N)`.

Of course, in the real world, it makes no sense to try to distribute a problem like this. The amount of time (per array element) to send the array elements over the network is significant. Much larger than the amount of time (per array element) needed to solve the problem on a single computer.

Comment: How can each node determine whether it contains the split point itself, if no assumption is made on the range of the input data (specifically, there can be negative numbers)?

Comment: @GZ0 You are correct that I was assuming non-negative array elements. With negative array elements, each node computes its best split point, and reports back its minimum difference, and its best split point. The control node then needs to make the final decision.

Comment: If it is a non-negative array the control node can already determine where the best split point is and send instructions only to the selected node.

Comment: @GZ0 Thanks for your insights. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the array is stored sequentially over several nodes N_1, ..., N_k. A simple distributed version of your original algorithm could be the following.

1. On each N_i, calculate the sum `s_i` of the subarray stored on N_i and send it to a control node M
2. On node M, using `s_1`, ..., `s_k`, calculate `leftSum_i` and `rightSum_i` for the left subarray boundary of each N_i and send them back to N_i
3. On each N_i, using `leftSum_i` and `rightSum_i`, conduct search to find the minimum `min_i` and send it back to M
4. On node M, calculate the global minimum `min` from `min_i`, ... `min_k`

A side note: your original algorithm can be optimized to keep only the value `rightSum - leftSum` rather than two separate values `leftSum` and `rightSum`. The distributed version can also be optimized correspondingly.